# R parsing multiple tables from a link page

Tags: r, web-scraping, datatables

I see there are many subject-related posts but I can't find a solution to this (surely my fault).

I am trying to scrape the tables issued on https://tradingeconomics.com and being a newbie in this I am facing issues.

I would like to get all the tables, plus the sub-tables by continent as per menu above each page.

Yet, I have tried to include all the links in an R vector and then to have a go on scraping by there but without any success:

```
 ## 00. Importing the main link
trading_ec <- read_html("https://tradingeconomics.com/indicators")


## 01. Scraping the variables names
tr_ec_tabs <- trading_ec %>%
  html_nodes(".list-group-item a") %>%
  html_text(trim=TRUE)


## 02. Editing the vector 
tr_ec_tabs_lo <- tolower(tr_ec_tabs)
tr_ec_nospace <- gsub(" ", "-", tr_ec_tabs_lo)


## 03. Creating a .json indicators vector
json.indicators <- paste0("https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/", tr_ec_nospace)

## 04. Function
table <- list()
for(i in seq_along(json.indicators))
{
  total_list <- readHTMLTable(json.indicators[i])
  n.rows <- unlist(lapply(total_list, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
  table[[i]] <- as.data.frame(total[[which.max(n.rows)]])
}
```

Comment: I see two tables on the site do you mean them?

Comment: the tables I am trying to parse are linked to this page: https://tradingeconomics.com/indicators?g=forecast

Comment: Is there something on the site that you can't use the API to get? (http://docs.tradingeconomics.com/?r#introduction)

Comment: No, but this is for particular work purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your loop with

```r
table <- list()
for(i in seq_along(json.indicators[-102]))
{
  table[[i]] <- html_table(read_html(json.indicators[i]))[[1]]
  cat("Page", i, "of", length(json.indicators[-102]), "obtained.\n")
}
```

You get a nice list of data frames. You have to drop index 102 because that links to a page without a table. Because it is a function that takes a while to run, I have added a `cat` statement that allows you to see how many pages you have scraped and how many are left.

Comment: Thanks. That would be the idea, actually.
Your code produces the following error message, though:

 
`      Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) : 
        invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
        In addition: Warning messages:
        1: In max(p) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
        2: In matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) :
         NAs introduced by coercion to integer range `

Comment: @Helena You are getting that error because the link stored in `json.indicators[102]` doesn't contain a table. If you try the updated code, it should work for you now. (I have tested it successfully)

Comment: Thanks a lot
For me it is working like that: 


     table <- list()
for(i in seq_along(json.indicators))
{
  table[[1]] <- html_table(read_html(json.indicators[1]))[[1]]
}


In any case, your solution fits and I put my vote on you.

Comment: Thanks Helena. If you find this answer useful, please mark it as accepted so that the community knows it has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: @Helena. I have just noticed the method you give in your comment will fill your list with multiple copies of the same data frame. My answer will give you all the different tables you need.